# Best way to pass parameter (very simple jquery/html)

Tags: jquery, html

I create multiple buttons using the username

```
<a id="message-' + onlineUsers[i].username + '"></a>
```

and then I would split the id by the `-` to get the username?

```
$('a[id^="message-"]').click(function () {
    //I need to get the username here
});
```

Somehow this doesn't look right to me. What's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data. It's the most commom way. And use class to get the click event.

```
<a class="message" data-username="' + onlineUsers[i].username + '"></a>
```

and, to get the data:

```
$(".message").click(function() {
    var username = $(this).data("username");
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style>
  </style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
      $('a[id^="message-"]').click(function () {
            //I need to get the username here
            var thisElem = jQuery(this);
            var lastItem = thisElem.attr("id").split("-").pop(-1);

            console.log(lastItem); //result "myusername"
        });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
       <a id="message-myusername">Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't like splitting it by dash, use it like <a id="message-myusername" ref="myusername">Click Me</a> so you can get it like: var username = jQuery(this).attr("ref");

Comment: Whatever way works for you is good. There can be so many ways to have it workable. You just pick one, we will make it workable.

Answer (score 0):

give each A tag same class and variable username in name tag like this

```
<a class="yourClassName" name="' + onlineUsers[i].username+'"></a>
```

now change your click function like this

```
$('.yourClassName').click(function () {
     alert( $(this).attr('name') );
}
```